# Efficient way of checking if value within boundaries defined in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a Python program that uses input data from an eye tracking device and checks if it is within a given range. The input is a normalized value and corresponds to the x position of gaze. The ranges are always sorted beforehand. I need to check if this position x is within boundaries in any pair of elements in a 2D array and run a function if that's the case. Something like:

```py
x = 0.23 # input variable
boundaries = [[0.0, 0.025], [0.025, 0.1], [0.1, 0.14], [0.15, 0.25]]

for i, pair in enumerate(boundaries):
    if x >= pair[0] and x <= pair[1]:
        print(i) # some function
```

Now, the catch is that the input x is realtime data emitted at 60Hz and the boundaries can be sometimes long lists (1000 elements), so there will be hundreds of thousands of checks per second with this approach. What would be the most efficient way to do this calculation? I imagine that perhaps there's a good vectorised version of this in numpy but I'm rather bad at calculus.

I have run a test to determine if the solution posted by @Meitham in the answers gives me a noticeable difference, I obtain however, using a Python approach:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
b1 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n)
boundaries = [[b1[i], b1[i] + 0.01] for i in range(n)]
x = 0.23
final = []

for i, pair in enumerate(boundaries):
    if x >= pair[0] and x <= pair[1]:
        final.append(pair)

100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0121 usec per loop
```

And the numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
b1 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n)
boundaries = [[b1[i], b1[i] + 0.01] for i in range(n)]
x = 0.23
a = np.array(boundaries)
final = a[(a[...,0] < x) & (a[...,1] > x)]

100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0122 usec per loop
```

So I see no meaningful difference between this two approaches. Maybe I'm testing it in the wrong way?

Comment: Are these tuples of boundaries always sorted, i.e. [(x, y)...] where always x <= y?

Comment: @Darien, can you clarify how exactly the boundaries are arranged? Can pairs intersect? From your example, Yn <= Xn+1. Is this always the case? If the answer is yes, then the optimal solution will be binary search

Comment: @Meitham, yes they always meet the condition x <= y

Comment: @IgorKleinerman. The pair of boundaries [(x,y), ...] always will be a starting point and an ending point where x != y is always is true and indeed Yn <= Xn+1 is also always true.

Comment: @Meitham, sorry, I could not edit up anymore. They are always sorted indeed but always x != y, so (x < y)

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is snap shot:]
`x = 0.23
boundaries = [[0.0, 0.025], [0.025, 0.1], [0.1, 0.14], [0.15, 0.25]]
filter_list = [item for item in boundaries if x >= item[0]  and x <= item[1] ]
print(filter_list)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> boundaries = [[0.0, 0.025], [0.025, 0.1], [0.1, 0.14], [0.15, 0.25], [1.0, 0.5]]
>>> x = 0.23
```

This uses numpy, and can work if the boundaries are reversed to::

```
>>> a = np.array(boundaries)
>>> (np.min(a, 1) < x) & (x < np.max(a, 1))
array([False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[(small < x) & (x < large)]
array([[ 0.15,  0.25]])
```

If the boundaries point (x, y) are guaranteed to be (x < y) then it's simpler and faster.

```
>>> a[(a[...,0] < x) & (a[...,1] > x)]
array([[ 0.15,  0.25]])
```

A pure python solution without `numpy` might look like below::

```
>>> [(low, high) for (low, high) in boundaries if high <= x <= low]
```

The python solution might appear fast for small sequences, like in the example, but `numpy` will shine when, as you stated in your question, the sequence of boundaries are large.

```
>>> %timeit [(low, high) for (low, high) in boundaries if high <= x <= low]
The slowest run took 26.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 419 ns per loop

>>> %timeit a[(a[...,0] < x) & (a[...,1] > x)]
The slowest run took 26.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.97 µs per loop

>>> %timeit (np.min(a, 1) < x) & (x < np.max(a, 1))
The slowest run took 40.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.22 µs per loop
```

Whereas, using a larger sequence of only 1000 elements::

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> %timeit [(low, high) for (low, high) in l if high <= x <= low]
The slowest run took 5.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 82 µs per loop
>>> a = np.array(l)
>>> %timeit a[(a[...,0] < x) & (a[...,1] > x)]
The slowest run took 6.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop
>>>
```

Comment: Although this is a nice solution there seems to be no performance difference:
`100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.012 usec per loop`
compared to:
`100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0121 usec per loop`
with the original approach

Comment: @Darien I've updated my answer with performance, as it's not clear from your comment what are the two ops you're measuring, I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for this. I was measuring a similar test than what you have here. I have updated my original post with details on my testing. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but as you can see I do not seem to have a major difference in performance. What could be the cause?